# failed codesign while building iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, profile, sign

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone CodeSign failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593180/iphone-codesign-failed)

ok, i know - often discussed - less solved. i want to build my app with an valid provision profile, downloaded from page and administrated with the xcode organiser. but nether the less i got

> Application failed codesign
>   verification. The signature was
>   invalid, or it was not signed with an
>   Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

i have the private key and the corresponding certificate in my keychain... so i have no idea, what to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tend to see it like that:
[Multiple Certificates/Provisioning Profiles in one Xcode organizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956988/multiple-certificates-provisioning-profiles-in-one-xcode-organizer)

despite that strange error - it is posible to provision the app on several devices. so i think i need to use the distrib. profile

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an Apple Worldwide Developer certificate in your keychain?

Do you have a provisioning profile for the app you're building?

Is this provisioning profile valid for the device you're building to (You can see this by going to the Organizer in XCode)?

Does the bundle identifier of the app you're building match the identifier in the provisioning profile you are signing it with?

N

Comment: yes to both - that is confusing

Comment: Apologies - I added a couple more things in an Edit to my post to look out for.

Comment: the device is matching and the identifier too - checked it twice ;)

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879473/how-to-fix-failed-codesign-verification-of-an-iphone-project - seems to be a similar error perhaps! And yes - these are really confusing errors!

Comment: you mean i should reinstall an older version of xcode? apple only provides 3.2.5 :/

Comment: No - this is wrong, sorry... I didn't look at the date on the post (2010). I use XCode 3.2.6 and all works fine for me. I've gone over all the obvious things that could be wrong I think!