# iOS XCode & Code Signing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, ios4

I am currently about to start work on an iOS app for somebody but they have there own Apple Developer account which they would like to us. How do I go about setting my MAC up so that I can use their account to build, develop and test their app on my Devices?

I am assuming that I will need to create a separate user account on my MAC. I have done this but when I try to install the certificates that they have created I get errors such as "Valid signing identity not found".

Why could Apple not make this process simple, I am always having to refer back to the documentation and still get confused just to start creating a new app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to create a new user account on your Mac for this, but I know some developers prefer to have separate accounts when they are working with more than one developer account, for ease of development & distribution provisioning profiles.

If your client adds you (by Apple ID --> email address) as a team member to their account (assuming their account belongs to a company and not an individual) then you can start the development process by requesting and later receiving a signed development certificate. You'll then also need the required provisioning profile(s) to develop/distribute builds of the app.

Comment: Great, thanks, works like a charm and stops having to have loads of user accounts on the mac. It was actually reasonably straight forward! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't need to create separate account. Xcode provide the facility to use several provisioning profile and certificate at the same time.

For more information check this thread - [Multiple Certificates/Provisioning Profiles in one Xcode organizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956988/multiple-certificates-provisioning-profiles-in-one-xcode-organizer)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to create new account on your Mac to develop iOS application. In Xcode 4 it become very easy to start developing and signing application. All you need to do is go to Organizer (most right button on Xcode toolbar). In Provisioning Profiles section you can see Refresh button on the botoom of the screen. When you click it ask you about your developer account information such as account name and password. Then it tries to install all profiles and certificates to your Mac automatically. Then you could select your profile and sign your app. If automatically install fails, check yourself that you download all you need for this.

1. Create keys on your mac and submit to Apple.
2. Download your certificate and WWDR certificate. Two!!!!
3. Add your device to the devices section and create Development certificate (Distribution as well ). Download it manually or via refresh in Xcode Organizer.

Hope it helps. Sergey!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your Apple Developer Account Credentials, You can follow gist I have created:

[Apple's Code Signing Process](https://gist.github.com/DalwadiV/2e43760d973c1d2baada)